# reading 2 analogue pins on the PIC

Tags: embedded, pic

I have some code to set-up and read an analogue input on a PIC16F690 PIC microcontroller

//set-up
    TRISA   = 0x01;       data direction register - set port A bit 0 as incoming ie RA0
    ANSEL   = 0x01;       set this pin as analogue 
    ADCON1  = 0x50;
    ADCON0  = 0x81;

```
while (1){
 unsigned char val = GETVALUE();
 wait();
}

unsigned char GETVALUE(void){

 unsigned short nRet; 
 ADCON0 |= 0x02;             // Start conversion

 while(ADCON0 & 0x02)        // wait for conversion
 {
 }
 nRet = ADRESH;
 nRet <<=8;
 nRet += ADRESL;

 return (nRet & 0x3FF);
}
```

which seems to work ok

If I want to read 2 pins (RA0 and RA1) alternating, how would I change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ADC mux value from 0 to 1 in `ADCON0` (bits: CHS0..CHS3) register, wait some time (some us to fill ADC sample capacitor) and call again `GETVALUE` function.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  Any idea of what is the min wait time in between swapping pins?

Comment: @user2633388: Check datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41262A.pdf section: 9-1 :ACQUISITION TIME EXAMPLE, how to calcolate it.